# Basis of a quotient vector space $\mathbb{R^2}/V$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

> Be $\mathbb{R^2}$ be the usual $\mathbb{R}-space$ of dimension 2. Let $V = \langle \left( 1, 1 \right) \rangle$ be the sub-space of $V$ generated by the vector $\left( 1, 1 \right)$.
> Give a basis of the quotient vector space $\mathbb{R^2}/V$.

---

I need some assistance to determine if my answer is correct.
Since $V$ is generated by $\left( 1, 1 \right)$, it implies that its span is simply a line $y = x$ passing through the origin. Therefore $\mathbb{R^2}/V := \left\{ all \ lines \ y = x + \lambda : \lambda \in \mathbb{R }\right\}$. Since all elements of the set are linearly independent, the only basis possible is $\left\{ all \ lines \ y = x + \lambda : \lambda \in \mathbb{R }\right\}$. Is the idea correct?

If it is, is the notation alright?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Are you claiming that a basis of $\Bbb R^2/V$ is $\Bbb R^2/V$ itself?

Comment: No, I am saying that the basis is the set of vectors that span the lines.

Comment: But aren't you saying that $\Bbb R^2/V=\{\text{all lines }y=x+\lambda:\lambda\in\Bbb R\}$ and that a basis a $\Bbb R^2/V$ is *also* $\{\text{all lines }y=x+\lambda:\lambda\in\Bbb R\}$?

Comment: $\Bbb R^2$ is $2$-dimensional, so $\Bbb R^2/V$ is at most $2$-dimensional. In fact it is $1$-dimensional, so a basis will be a set containing just one element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\dim\Bbb R^2=2$ and $\dim V=1$, $\dim(\Bbb R^2/V)=2-1=1$. So, take *any* element $\alpha$ other than $0$ from $\Bbb R^2/V$, and $\{\alpha\}$ will be a basis of $\Bbb R^2/V$. For instance, take $\alpha=(1,0)+V$.

Comment: Thanks, I got it! It can be any vector other than V.